# Automator Folder Action workflow to copy a file to one folder and then move it to another folder

Tags: automator, folder-action

I need an Automator Folder Action workflow that when files are dropped into the folder the workflow is assigned to, it will first make a copy of the dropped files to one different folder, and then move the original dropped files to another different folder.

For example, say I want to drop a single file into a "Hot Folder", then have that file first copied to a different folder, and then the same file that was first copied, moved to another different folder.

This would leave the folder the file was originally dropped into empty while now having the originally dropped file in two different location by the Automator Folder Action workflow, one by copying it and the other by moving the file the copy was made from.

Can someone show me how to do this with Automator?

Comment: What have you got so far (even if it only moves the file to one location)?

Comment: You can't move a file to two different folders. You would copy the file to two different folders or copy the file to one folder then move the file to the other folder.

Comment: @fd0 I'm quite sure that copying to two folders and deleting the source is exactly what the OP wants :-)

Comment: I tried the copy then move option, but I could only get the first copy to run. It seems like the script stops after the copy and will not complete the final move. I am using Folder Actions in Automator.

Comment: If you have something already, please add it. You will benefit more from an improved version of your own script than from one somebody else wrote

Answer (score 2):

This following *example* **Automator Folder Action** *workflow* works for me.

This was tested with one file and many files at a time over a half dozen tests with different file counts and sizes, however I'd caution that this simple workflow might choke if invoked with to many really large files at one time.

Setup the *workflow* according to the individual *actions* in the order shown in the image further below and the **Options** shown on the two **Get Value of Variable** *actions*.  Which are in order:

- Start with setting the *target folder* for: **Folder Action receives files and folders added to**
- Add a **Set Value of Variable** *action*, giving the **Variable:** a pertinent *name*.
- Add a **Get Value of Variable** *action*, while setting the value of the **Variable:** list box to the *value* of **Variable:** set in the **Set Value of Variable** *action*, and check the **[√] Ignore this actions input** check box under its **Options**.
- Add a **Copy Finder Items** *action*, while setting the **To:** list box to a pertinent *target folder*.
- Add a **Get Value of Variable** *action*, while setting the value of the **Variable:** list box to the *value* of **Variable:** set in the **Set Value of Variable** *action*, and check the **[√] Ignore this actions input** check box under its **Options**.
- Add a **Move Finders Items** action, while setting the **To:** list box to the a pertinent *target folder*.

[image]

**Note:** This *workflow* choice was made to show how to accomplish the task without the use of *shell scripting* and a **Run Shell Script** *action*, as some users may not be comfortable using *shell scripting*.

---

If you are comfortable using *shell scripting*, then this *example* **Automator Folder Action** *workflow* works for me too.

Setup the *workflow* according to the individual *action* shown in the image further below:

- Start with setting the *target folder* for: **Folder Action receives files and folders added to**
- Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*, while changing **Pass input:** from **to stdin** to **as arguments**. Then replace the original *code* with the following example code, while modifying the *value* of the `copy` and `movef`*variables* to contain the `POSIX pathname` of the *target folders* the file is to be copied to first, and subsequently moved to from the "Hot Folder" it was dropped into.

  ```
  copyf="/Path/To/Copy To Folder"
  movef="/Path/To/Move To Folder"

  for f in "$@"; do
      cp -a "$f" "$copyf"
      mv "$f" "movef"
  done
  ```

[image]

Comment: To whomever down-voted this answer, please provide a legitimate reason for it as this is a working Automator Folder Action workflow for me in my testing and ultimately does what the OP asked for. If it doesn't work for you then you should comment on it that it didn't, so I can then help fix what may be wrong on your system.

Comment: Wouldn‘t it be easier to just use a shell script action?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did get the Automator workflow to work, but it appears that the files remain in the Hot Folder after they are sent to the output folders. Is there a way to actually MOVE the folder in the last step? It appears that is is being copied and not moved in the last step.

Comment: Also, tried my hand at shell scripting, but what a wrote did not appear to work either. The files were not copied/moved to the paths I included. However, the source file was removed from the Hot Folder, so it was being moved somewhere, just not to the paths I entered as variables.

Comment: copyf="smb://traco-hpindigo/hot_folders/PSLABEL1-CMYK/"  
        movef="smb://traco-hpindigo2/hot_folders/PSLABEL2-CMYK/". 

        for f in "$@"; do  
        cp -a "$f" "$copyf"  
        mv "$f" "movef"  
    done

Comment: @Gawly, You need to `mount` the SMB Shares and use the _local path_ to the _mount point and beyond_ for `copyf="/Path/To/Copy To Folder"` and `movef="/Path/To/Move To Folder"`. Also, in the future I'd strongly suggest you include all relevant details in your question!

Comment: Is there a way of doing this move action ON DEMAND? So I open the created automator app and then the operation is performed (not automatically). I'm not familiar with shell scripts, so I'd prefer to use the standard action designer. Thanks